# How can I show multiple values for a row? (Excel Pivot Table)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table, pivot-chart

As far as I am aware, the values in pivot table can only be shown as a sum, average, count etc. but not as a list of the raw values?

What I am looking for is to list all the times ran for each distance in their own column, rather than a sum of all the times ran as it is shown currently.

My problem:

[source data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTnIO.jpg)

[pivot table currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEh8R.jpg)

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want the result to look like (can you post a mock-up?).  But would it achieve what you're looking for to  add times as another row field?

Comment: PivotTable integrate all data but not list them each.